# Verilog code color lost

Tags: vim, verilog

I am working on Verilog using gvim editor on Linux OS.
Because of system failure I lost some of the files.
Previously predefined variables of verilog code used to come in colors but not now.
How can I get those colors back ?
PLease Help !!

Comment: And, a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=gvim+syntax+highlighting) will probably help you quicker.

Comment: if you're working with the theorem prover/proof assistant `coq` - it's file extension too is `.v`, so this may interfere with your setup too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you just not have to turn on syntax.

```
:syntax on
```

Or add this in to your vimrc file

```
syntax on
```

The loss of colouring could be due to missing verilog syntax files, mine can be found [here](https://github.com/morganp/dotfiles/tree/master/vim/syntax). I also have a ftplugin [here](https://github.com/morganp/dotfiles/tree/master/vim/ftplugin).

I use the following line in my [.vimrc](https://github.com/morganp/dotfiles/blob/master/dotfiles/.vimrc) to force the filetype detection:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.v,*.vh,*.args,*.f,*.verilog set ft=verilog
```